# R What does ?? (two question marks) mean vs. ? (one question mark)

Tags: r

Quick question - hoping for some help.

I'm practicing in R. I type this into the console:

```
?mtcars
```

And I see in the bottom-right hand quadrant of RStudio information about mtcars.

Later on, I'm trying to convert something as a factor:

```
mtcars$am <-as_factor(mtcars$am)
```

But I get this error message:

```
Error in as_factor(mtcars$am) : could not find function "as_factor"
```

So I try to explore what that means by looking at the help section:

```
?as_factor
```

But I get this error message:

```
No documentation for ‘as_factor’ in specified packages and libraries:
you could try ‘??as_factor’
```

I follow the advice and see that as factor is in the forcats library, which I guess I didn't have loaded.

How should I think about the difference between looking for help documentation using one question mark ?mtcars vs two question marks ??as_factor? Is there a heuristic for this?

Comment: `?` searches in *loaded* packages, whereas `??` extends the  search to *installed* packages.

Comment: You can search "?help.search"

Comment: Or you can type `?\`??\``.

Comment: @MartinGal, I feel like that's a recursive answer ... to be able to know to try `?\`??\``, you need to know what `?`, but can you `?\`?\`` (which doesn't work, btw)? Should one think to do that? (This is not a criticism, kind of the Inception of answering "what is `?`/`??`".)

Comment: @r2evans Actually `?\`?\`` does work (at least on my machine). Basically you *are* right, but I was curious, if `?\`??\`` does work and I thought it was a funny comment. On the other hand: I didn't even know that `??` existed, but I used `?` before. So... is it really recursive?

Comment: Also relevant/recommended/required reading: [R-Intro 1.7 Getting help with functions and features](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Getting-help)

Comment: (@MartinGal, for me, `?\`?\`` does not work, using emacs/ess. To see it, I need to use `help("?")`. \*shrug\*)